# Convert integers to strings to create output filenames at run time

Tags: string, integer, fortran

I have a program in Fortran that saves the results to a file. At the moment I open the file using

```
OPEN (1, FILE = 'Output.TXT')
```

However, I now want to run a loop, and save the results of each iteration to the files `'Output1.TXT'`, `'Output2.TXT'`, `'Output3.TXT'`, and so on.

Is there an easy way in Fortran to constuct filenames from the loop counter `i`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

you can write to a unit, but you can also write to a string

```
program foo
    character(len=1024) :: filename

    write (filename, "(A5,I2)") "hello", 10

    print *, trim(filename)
end program
```

Please note (this is the second trick I was talking about) that you can also build a format string programmatically.

```
program foo

    character(len=1024) :: filename
    character(len=1024) :: format_string
    integer :: i

    do i=1, 10
        if (i < 10) then
            format_string = "(A5,I1)"
        else
            format_string = "(A5,I2)"
        endif

        write (filename,format_string) "hello", i
        print *, trim(filename)
    enddo

end program
```

Comment: Two comments:
 - you don't have to discriminate on the value of I; the format (I0) will output an integer without any space; also, if you want a fixed width and padding with zeroes (like "output001.txt"), you need to used (I0.3)
 - the format (A5I2) is not valid Fortran according to any norm, as format specifiers are to be separated by commas: (A5,I2)

Comment: Well, it was for educational purposes, not intended to be the solution. In general I use the padding zeros (as it sorts nicely), but the I0 thingie I didn't know about. Thanks!! (fixed the commas, I think my style was the old one, still accepted)

Comment: @F'x thanks for the comment, really useful. Indeed even trim won't work if the number k of digits is not equal to "(Ik)" in the format, so just use "(I0)" so that one doesn't need to adapt the format.

Comment: There is not A0 as the counterpart of I0, right? (meaning a character string with any padding)

Comment: @ManuelPena *"w shall be zero or positive for the I, B, O, Z, D, E, EN, ES, EX, F, and G edit descriptors. **w shall be positive for all other edit descriptors**."* (Fortran 2018, where *w* is the width parameter). However, the width is not mandatory for the A edit descriptor, and if omitted, the length of the character string is used instead. But bear in mind that this length includes any trailing space: if you want to remove them from the output, use the A edit descriptor (without length parameter) **and** pass `trim(s)` instead of `s`. You may also want to `adjustl`.

Answer (score 22):

A much easier solution IMHO ...................

```
character(len=8) :: fmt ! format descriptor

fmt = '(I5.5)' ! an integer of width 5 with zeros at the left

i1= 59

write (x1,fmt) i1 ! converting integer to string using a 'internal file'

filename='output'//trim(x1)//'.dat'

! ====> filename: output00059.dat
```

Comment: may just be my compiler, but i was needed to declare a character variable for the output string written to (i.e. `character(5) x1`). thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Well here is a simple function which will return the left justified string version of an integer:

```
character(len=20) function str(k)
!   "Convert an integer to string."
    integer, intent(in) :: k
    write (str, *) k
    str = adjustl(str)
end function str
```

And here is a test code:

```
program x
integer :: i
do i=1, 100
    open(11, file='Output'//trim(str(i))//'.txt')
    write (11, *) i
    close (11)
end do
end program x
```

Answer (score 8):

I already showed this elsewhere on SO ([How to use a variable in the format specifier statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27189975/721644) , not an exact duplicate IMHO), but I think it is worthwhile to place it here. It is possible to use the techniques from other answers for this question to make a simple function

```
function itoa(i) result(res)
  character(:),allocatable :: res
  integer,intent(in) :: i
  character(range(i)+2) :: tmp
  write(tmp,'(i0)') i
  res = trim(tmp)
end function
```

which you can use after without worrying about trimming and left-adjusting and without writing to a temporary variable:

```
OPEN(1, FILE = 'Output'//itoa(i)//'.TXT')
```

It requires Fortran 2003 because of the allocatable string.

Answer (score 3):

For a shorten version.
If all the indices are smaller than 10, then use the following:

```
do i=0,9
   fid=100+i
   fname='OUTPUT'//NCHAR(i+48) //'.txt'
   open(fid, file=fname)
   !....
end do
```

For a general version:

```
character(len=5) :: charI
do i = 0,100
   fid = 100 + i
   write(charI,"(A)"), i
   fname ='OUTPUT' // trim(charI) // '.txt'
   open(fid, file=fname)
end do
```

That's all.

Comment: There should be no comma after after the closing parentheses in write statement. ((     write(charI,"(A)") i     ))
  
Thanks, I am using this suggestion.

Comment: The default is no comma, but I found it works well if the additional comma added, similar as ((print *, i))

Answer (score 1):

I've tried @Alejandro and @user2361779 already but it gives me an unsatisfied result such as `file   1.txt` or `file1   .txt` instead of `file1.txt`. However i find the better solution:

```
...
integer :: i
character(len=5) :: char_i     ! use your maximum expected len
character(len=32) :: filename

write(char_i, '(I5)') i        ! convert integer to char
write(filename, '("path/to/file/", A, ".dat")') trim(adjustl(char_i))
...
```

Explanation:

e.g. set `i = 10` and `write(char_i, '(I5)') i`

```
char_i                gives  "   10" ! this is original value of char_i

adjustl(char_i)       gives  "10   " ! adjust char_i to the left

trim(adjustl(char_i)) gives  "10"    ! adjust char_i to the left then remove blank space on the right
```

I think this is a simplest solution that give you a dynamical length filename without any legacy blank spaces from integer to string conversion process.

Comment: Using `I0` as the edit descriptor would be much simpler: `write(filename, '("path/to/file/", I0, ".dat")') i`.  This is mentioned previously in this question only in comments, so perhaps could be added.

Comment: Thank you @francescalus, I didn't notice that comment. Then left my answer to be an alternative solution. it may be useful in some case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    ....
    character(len=30) :: filename  ! length depends on expected names
    integer           :: inuit
    ....
    do i=1,n
        write(filename,'("output",i0,".txt")') i
        open(newunit=iunit,file=filename,...)
        ....
        close(iunit)
    enddo
    ....
```

Where "..." means other appropriate code for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for writing files for different parameters in a loop

```
program sinnx_diff_n
implicit none
integer :: n, xloop
real*8  :: x,y
character(len=40)  :: nchar

do n=1,4
    
    write(nchar,6)n
    6 format(I5)    

    open (8,file="data-x-vs-y-n="//trim(adjustl(nchar))//"-values.dat", status="replace",action="write")   ! this line is storing data for each n value.

    do xloop=-40,40
        x=real(xloop)/10.0d0
        y=sin(n*x)            ! writing y = sin(x) for a single n value
        write(8,34)x,y
        34 format(2x, 10f16.8)  ! this will accommodate 10 columns of real values with gap of 2 spaces between each data column.
    end do            ! end of x loop

end do  ! end of different n loop   
    
end program
```

Answer (score -2):

To convert an integer to a string:

```
integer :: i    
character* :: s    
if (i.LE.9) then
     s=char(48+i)    
else if (i.GE.10) then
     s=char(48+(i/10))// char(48-10*(i/10)+i)    
endif
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is my subroutine approach to this problem. it transforms an integer in the range  0 : 9999 as a character.  For example, the INTEGER  123 is transformed into the character 0123. hope it helps.

P.S. - sorry for the comments; they make sense in Romanian :P

```
 subroutine nume_fisier (i,filename_tot)

   implicit none
   integer :: i

   integer :: integer_zeci,rest_zeci,integer_sute,rest_sute,integer_mii,rest_mii
   character(1) :: filename1,filename2,filename3,filename4
   character(4) :: filename_tot

! Subrutina ce transforma un INTEGER de la 0 la 9999 in o serie de CARACTERE cu acelasi numar

! pentru a fi folosite in numerotarea si denumirea fisierelor de rezultate.

 if(i<=9) then

  filename1=char(48+0)
  filename2=char(48+0)
  filename3=char(48+0)
  filename4=char(48+i)  

 elseif(i>=10.and.i<=99) then

  integer_zeci=int(i/10)
  rest_zeci=mod(i,10)
  filename1=char(48+0)
  filename2=char(48+0)
  filename3=char(48+integer_zeci)
  filename4=char(48+rest_zeci)

 elseif(i>=100.and.i<=999) then

  integer_sute=int(i/100)
  rest_sute=mod(i,100)
  integer_zeci=int(rest_sute/10)
  rest_zeci=mod(rest_sute,10)
  filename1=char(48+0)
  filename2=char(48+integer_sute)
  filename3=char(48+integer_zeci)
  filename4=char(48+rest_zeci)

 elseif(i>=1000.and.i<=9999) then

  integer_mii=int(i/1000)
  rest_mii=mod(i,1000)
  integer_sute=int(rest_mii/100)
  rest_sute=mod(rest_mii,100)
  integer_zeci=int(rest_sute/10)
  rest_zeci=mod(rest_sute,10)
  filename1=char(48+integer_mii)
  filename2=char(48+integer_sute)
  filename3=char(48+integer_zeci) 
  filename4=char(48+rest_zeci)

 endif

 filename_tot=''//filename1//''//filename2//''//filename3//''//filename4//''
 return
 end subroutine nume_fisier
```

Comment: This is a very bad answer.  As the accepted answer already shows Fortran provides a mechanism for writing the value of an integer into a character variable; all this fiddling around with encoding and decoding character indices is a horrid hack which serves no useful purpose.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Regarding his name, this code looks quite reasonable.