# Fortran: user defined integer in file name of "open" statement

Tags: fortran, user-defined

I want to open a file in fortran with file name "controlinputs.12.dat" and then write into that file. The digit "12" is user defined variable whose value is stored in another variable "k". I have tried following and failed.

```
k=12
open(10,filename='controlinputs.',k,'.dat')
```

Tried storing the name in character and then using character to open file.

```
k=12
fname='controlinputs.',k,'.dat'
open(10,filaname=fname)
```

Comment: Previous answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146516/writing-multiple-output-files-in-fortran, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291270/looping-over-variable-file-names and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262695/converting-integers-to-strings-in-fortran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was very simple. I didn't knew how to concatenate characters. I was reading the integer 12 from a file so I saved it in character type then simply used following.

```
character::k*5
open(10,filename='controlinputs.'//trim(k)//'.dat')
```