# Concatenate two integers

Tags: fortran, concatenation, integer

What is the best way to concatenate two integers to an integer in Fortran?

```
integer a = 999
integer b = 1111
```

`integer c`  should be `9991111`

Thanks,
SM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example code that does what you need. It writes integers into character strings, trims and concatenetes them, and then reads the result integer from concatenated character string:

```
integer :: a,b,c
character(len=99) :: char_a,char_b,char_c

a = 999
b = 1111

write(unit=char_a,fmt=*)a
write(unit=char_b,fmt=*)b

char_c = trim(adjustl(char_a))//trim(adjustl(char_b))

read(unit=char_c,fmt=*)c

print*,c

end
```

Edit: Note that this example is general for any integer lengths, assuming they fit into their respective `kind` (no integer overflow).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the information of the order of the number:

```
integer :: a = 999
integer :: b = 1111

integer :: c

c = a * 10**(ceiling(log10(real(b)))) + b

write(*,*) c
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use [internal files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262695/converting-integers-to-strings-in-fortran) to convert your two integers to a character, and then convert this back to an integer.

There is no intrinsic procedure for converting a numeric value to a character/string representation. See [this](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/ichar) discusson on Fortran Wiki for more information (see the part headed "Note").

As an example, in your case you could use the following:

```
program test_conversion
  implicit none

  integer :: a=999
  integer :: b=1111
  integer :: c

  character(len=7) :: temp

  write(temp, '(i3.3, i4.4)') a, b ! You may need to change these format specifiers

  read(temp, *) c

  print*, c ! This prints 9991111

end program test_conversion
```

You will have to change the format string if you want different widths of the character representation of your integers.

Comment: The line 'write(c, *) temp' does not do what you think. It will write temp into a I/O unit having a value of integer c, and not into c itself. Instead, you need to read c from temp.

Comment: That was an mistype on my part - copied and pasted from the line above. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No problem. Just out of curiosity, I tried your code with ifort, pgf90 and gfortran. Strangely enough, ifort12 seems to write temp into integer c and print it, which is not expected/desired behavior. pgf90 and gfortran behave as expected, generating fort.gibberish files as output.

Comment: I assume you mean my previous, incorrect code? I just tried it with gfortran under cygwin and it also writes temp into an integer and prints it, which is rather strange.

Comment: Yes, I mean the previous code. I always enjoy discovering bugs in compilers though.