# How to name output files, making it related to a variable (in fortran)?

Tags: parameters, fortran, output

Eg. The integer variable (m) will take the following values one by one:

**1**, **2**, **3**, ....

For each value of m, an array

**p(i) (i=1,2,..., 1000)**

is obtained and written in a output file with

`open()` and `write()`

Could you tell me how to name these output files as

**file1.dat**, **file2.dat**, **file3.dat**, …

Thanks.

Comment: Write the integer into an array and adjustl that string, the concatanate it with the pre- and post-fix?

Comment: @haraldkl I do not need to write the integer into arrays ,but just want to name the output files, making these files include specific value of m, therefore they are distinguishable.

Comment: You should show us some code, what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry, didn't want to say array but character string...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262695/converting-integers-to-strings-in-fortran and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291270/looping-over-variable-file-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here is a suggestion:

```
integer :: m
integer :: fu
character(len=10) :: file_id
character(len=50) :: file_name

! Write the integer into a string:
write(file_id, '(i0)') m

! Construct the filename:
file_name = 'file' // trim(adjustl(file_id)) // '.dat'

! Open the file with this name
open(file = trim(file_name), unit = fu)
```

Note, that you could also obtain leading zeroes with the iX.Y format string.

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful answer and comments.  In the last line, I replace `name` with `file`. I tried and then it works!

Comment: Oh, sorry. Corrected that now.

Answer (score 2):

Googling "internal write fortran" shows how to create strings that embed the integer variable, which is demonstrated in the following program, which creates the string "file1.dat".

```
program internal_write
character (len=10) :: file_name
write (file_name,"('file',i0,'.dat')") 1
print*,"file name is ",trim(file_name)
end program internal_write
```