How do I write to an allocatable character variable?
I have a subroutine that's essentially a logger. It takes in a required string, as well as two optional parameters that it formats.
Here's a simplified version. Currently this fails when writing to action_local
subroutine log(required_param, action, idx)
    character(len=*), intent(in) :: required_param
    character(len=*), intent(in), optional :: action
    integer, intent(in), optional :: idx
    character(:), allocatable :: action_local

10  format(A, A, I)

    if (present(action) .and. present(idx)) then
        write(action_local, 10) ' ', action, idx ! fails: action_local is not allocated
    else
        action_local = ''
    end if

    print *, required_param // action_local
end subroutine

Ideally I wouldn't guess at the size required - I'd just let the output of the write statement allocate what it needs. Is there a way to write to an allocatable character without allocating it ahead of time?

In a Fortran 2023 write statement, an internal file which is an allocatable deferred-length scalar character variable is defined according to the rules of intrinsic assignment. This includes first allocating it to the correct length if required.
That is, in the form of the question
write(action_local, 10) ' ', action, idx

the action_local is the internal file, and it's indeed scalar, allocatable and deferred-length. There is no need to allocate it before the data transfter statement.
You don't have a Fortran 2023 compiler.
You will need to allocate its length first (such as in your own answer) or manually use intrinsic assignment (such as using the various techniques found in answer elsewhere).

I do not have a Fortran 2023 compiler :'(

@Adam nobody has at the moment, there is no Fortran 2023 compliant compiler yet.

@PierU that makes me feel a little better

And even when you have a F2023 compiler (or at least a compiler which implements this part), you can't write code which assumes everyone has a F2023 compiler.

It seems this may not be possible from this source. The example code allocates suitably large amount of space before trimming it down.

Where the function name returns a character value there there is no actual argument requiring a length match so it will usually be best to declare the function name to have allocatable length. If the value is assigned in an assignment statement nothing more is required, but if it gets a value from an I/O operation it may need to have its length allocated first (or else write first to a temporary fixed-length string).

function int_to_string(intval) result (funcname)
    integer, intent(in)           :: intval   
    character(len=:), allocatable :: funcname
    ! initially allocate enough length for largest possible integer
    allocate(character(len=12) :: funcname)
    write(funcname, '(i0)') intval
    ! then reallocate
    funcname = trim(funcname)
end function int_to_string

In this case,
! allocate enough space for action plus integer plus space
allocate(character(len=len(action) + 13) :: action_local)


Yes, this is exactly what I have shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27190323/721644 but you have to know what the largest possible string is and you have the overhead of reallocation. You have the pre-allocate to the right size, unlike what Fortran 2023 wiůl allow as francescalus have shown.

I prefer to store all optional formal arguments as a local variable (in string form). If optional actual argument is not present, then store blank string in it.
Here is my version of your log subroutine:
For the action optional argument:

If action exists, store ' ' plus action in myaction local variable.
If action doesn't exist, store blank screen in myaction local variable.

For the idx optional argument:

If idx exists, store ' ' plus idx converted to string in myidx local variable.
If idx doesn't exist, store blank screen in myidx local variable.

Then we can forget optional arguments:
  subroutine log(required_param, action, idx)
    character(len=*), intent(in) :: required_param
    character(len=*), intent(in), optional :: action
    integer, intent(in), optional :: idx

    character(:), allocatable :: action_local, myaction, myidx

    if (present(action)) then
      myaction = ' ' // action
    else
      myaction = ''
    end if

    if (present(idx)) then
      allocate(character(len=2+int(log10(real(idx)))) :: myidx)
      write(myidx, '(" ",i0)') idx
    else
      myidx = ''
    end if

    action_local = myaction // myidx

    print '(a)', required_param // action_local
  end subroutine log


Thanks - this code contains the manual allocation to the integer itself, but is my answer correct in that manual allocation is still always required? I should've mentioned in my code I can make the assumption that both parameters will be present or absent together, hence my original if checked both.

Manual allocation for the integer argument idx is necessary.
