# Default behavior of OPEN with STATUS='NEW'

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am compiling a program (that I did not write) using gfortran. The make file specified f77 as the compiler, but I do not have it.

I have run into an error related to the OPEN command.

```
Error: The STATUS specified in OPEN statement at (1) is 'NEW' and no FILE specifier is present
```

I looked into Fortran 77 OPEN, and according to the Oracle language reference there is a default behaviour when 'FILE=name' is not specified.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnaf/index.html

'NEW' -- The file doesn't exist (existence is an error). If 'FILE=name' is not specified, then a file named 'fort.n' is opened, where n is the specified logical unit.

Is there a way to force the compiler to use the language specified default behaviour. Alternatively, can I modify the code to perform the expected default behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document you cite is not a language specification, it is a description of one particular compiler. The behaviour regarding the file `fort.n` is compiler specific. For actual standard documents see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran/info

Specifically, the Fortran 2008 says:

> 9.5.6.10  FILE= specifier in the OPEN statement
>
> 1 The value of the FILE= specifier is the name of the file to be connected to the
>   specified unit. Any trailing blanks are ignored. The file-name-expr
>   shall be a name that is allowed by the processor. If this specifier is
>   omitted and the unit is not connected to a file, the STATUS= specifier
>   shall be specified with a value of SCRATCH; in this case, the
>   connection is made to a processor-dependent file. The interpretation
>   of case is processor dependent.

That means that your program is not conforming, because when `FILE=` is omited, the only permissible value of `STATUS=` is `"SCRATCH"`.

Gfortran also does create the `fort.n` files when you write to a unit which you did not open, but not when you execute the `open` statement with `status="new"`. It should be easy for you to add the `file=` specifier to the code. You can even use the `fort.N` names if you insist on them. See [Convert integers to strings to create output filenames at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262695/converting-integers-to-strings-in-fortran) for the way how to get the integer into the file name.

Another option is to download the [Oracle Solaris Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/overview/index-jsp-142272.html), it contains the `f77` command and is likely to follow the compiler specific document you have cited. It is actually quite a good compiler (if lacking some modern Fortran features) with very good visual debugging and profiling utilities. However, I recommend you to make your code portable and standard conforming first.