# List the content of a directory specified by loop indices

Tags: shell, fortran

I'm working with numerical weather forecast  named as follow:

```
sub_gfsanl_4_2011MMDD-IIII-FFFF.grb2
```

-MM stands for month  from 01 to 12

-DD stands for days   from 01 to 31

-IIII stands for initialisation time, the first and second digits are for hours the third and last are for minutes

-FFFF stands for forecast hour , the first and second digits are for hours the third and last are for minutes

In my directory I have several files for a given days of a given months. A day has 4 data, one at every six hours IIII=0000 ,0600,1200,1800.

What I'm trying to do is to list all files of a given days, here the f90 code I wrote:

```
program test_ec

implicit none

!==variable declaration==

integer :: mi,di,dil,mil
character*3 :: temp

!==Program instructions==

mil=1
write(temp,'(i2.2)') mil
read(temp,'(i2.2)') mi
!convert the month into a two digit value mi=01  


 ! change to directory where the data are stored
 CALL chdir('/media/Hello/ncfiles/GFS' )

do dil=1,31

     !loop over days
     write(temp,'(i2.2)') dil
     read(temp,'(i2.2)') di

     ! converting day number into a two digit number, store this value into di. ex dil=9 then di=09

CALL execute_command_line( 'ls sub_gfsanl_4_2011${mi}${di}*.nc > yes.txt' )
!list all files with the correct month and days and store it to yes.txt

end do

end program test_ec
```

For some reasons the `execute_command_line` doesn't seem to like the $ for variable...

Comment: What does *"doesn't seem to like the $ for variable"* mean? Are there any error messages? Wrong results? Which results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `${mi}${di}` in shell. They are Fortran variables, not shell variables. You must put the numbers into the string inside Fortran. Use some of the established methods. They were treated here many times in [Convert integers to strings to create output filenames at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262695/converting-integers-to-strings-in-fortran) and its duplicates (see Related on the right).

Comment: I don' t know how to edit my previous message..

Well it's a little more complex than that, the method you show don't work for my case i just provided a little sample of the original code (2000 lines...) to not confuse people.

So here a little more information :

I try ty concatenate the content all netcdf forecast file for a day!
Remember sometimes there is three file other times four.

That why i need to loop over the days and i can't use the method you suggested!

Do you have any on how to pass my fortran variable into shell?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to Vladimir suggestion here what i did to solve my problem!

```
program test_ec


implicit none

integer :: mi,di,iiii,fff
 character(len=1024) :: filename
 character(len=1024) :: format_string
 logical exist

mi=1
CALL chdir('/media/Hello/ncfiles/GFS' )

!do di=1,10
     do iiii=0,18,6
         do fff=0,18,6

                   format_string = "(A17,i2.2,i2.2,A1,i4.4,A1,i3.3,A8)"
                    write (filename,format_string) "sub_gfsanl_4_2011",mi,di,"_",iiii,"_",fff,".grb2.nc"

                    inquire(file=trim(filename), exist=exist) 

                           if (exist) then

                                   write(*,*) 'file exists i can do do whatever i want with this file'
                           else
                                   write(*,*) 'I did not find that file.'

                           end if
enddo
   enddo
     enddo

end program test_ec
```

Comment: I would suggest a dimensioned CHARACTER(LEN=2) for the DD and MM. The other option is some code to add a 0 before DD and MM between 1-9. Both work fine, just the former uses something like day(DD) where DD is the integer index of the character array Day.