# INQUIRE to find files with certain extension in Fortran

Tags: fortran

My problem is that I want to inquire for an unknown filename in Fortran by using the extension of the file.

Example: a folder has a file with an extension "*.cel", the extension is always the same but the filename can be different because is given by the end-users. I want to detect whether any *.cel exists in the folder and get the name of the file.

Comment: you need to work with `execute_command_line` see here for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/40117357/1004168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of file system interaction is a bit hard. You'd think that someone would have created a module for that, but there are precious few, and I haven't come across one that was easy to use.

What most people do is either use a specific call to the `system` or `execute_command_line` subroutines to let the shell do the work, see here:

```
program my_ls

    use iso_fortran_env
    implicit none
    character(len=*), parameter :: ls_file = '/tmp/my_ls.tmp'
    integer :: u, ios
    character(len=30) :: filename

    call execute_command_line('ls -1 > '//ls_file, wait=.TRUE., exitstat=ios)
    if (ios /= 0) stop "Unable to get listing"

    open(newunit=u, file=ls_file, iostat=ios, status="old", action="read")
    if ( ios /= 0 ) stop "Error opening listing file "

    do
        read(u, *, iostat=ios) filename
        if (is_iostat_end(ios)) exit
        if (ios /= 0) STOP "Unexpected error while reading listing file"
        if (index(filename, ".cel") > 0) then
            print*, filename
        end if
    end do

    close(u)

    call execute_command_line('rm '//ls_file, wait=.FALSE.)

end program my_ls
```

But what would be easier is to give the filenames as a command line argument when starting the program:

```
program my_ls2

    use iso_fortran_env
    implicit none

    integer :: num_files, i
    character(len=64), allocatable :: filenames(:)

    num_files = command_argument_count()
    allocate(filenames(num_files))
    do i = 1, num_files
        call get_command_argument(i, filenames(i))
    end do

    write(*, '(A)') filenames

end program my_ls2
```

Calling this program with

```
$ my_ls2 *.cel
```

will give you every file you want.

Comment: Just a note: In the first example, it would probably be safer, simpler, and faster, to let the `ls` command do the checking for the `.cel` extension: `'ls -1 *.cel > ' // ls_file`, but I wanted to leave the `index` call in to show an example for how to look for filename parts.

Comment: Just wanted to point out you are assuming the poster is always in a Unix like environment via the use of ls, or at least an environment where ls lists files

Comment: You are of course right. However, if I were using another operating system, I would probably use the corresponding commands. So this should give even windows users a pointer to how this can be done

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: I'm afraid you can't do that in standard Fortran. You're going to have to look at your compiler documentation to find if it supports an extension through which you can implement what you require.