# Reading multiple files and storing data in fortran 77

Tags: fortran

Hi I am using Fortran 77. I need to read multiple files and store the values. The details are following.

1. I have files with names tau_modelC_total_z0.30.dat, tau_modelC_total_z0.31.dat,tau_modelC_total_z0.32.dat.........tau_modelC_total_z1.00, nearly 100 files.
2. Each file contains two column data of E and tau values. Each file is for particular z (as indicated in name of the file) and it increases in step size of 0.01. Basically, for each data file, I have E and tau values for particular z value. E values are same in all the data files.
3. I want to store z, E and tau values say x1a is the array of z values, x2a is the array for E values and ya is the array for tau such that tau(z,E) ie, a function of both z and E. I want to use this array for the interpolation so that I can get tau value for any z and E.

Please tell me how can I do that .

Comment: Welcome, please take the welcome [tour] and read [ask]. Please show us your code, it is very important. Your current question is way too broad for this site, you need to ask a single question and not ask how to do a lot of work. Show us the actual problem you have with your code.

Comment: How to read files namied tau_modelC_total_z0.30.dat, tau_modelC_total_z0.31.dat,tau_modelC_total_z0.32.dat.........tau_modelC_total_z1.00, nearly 100 files with fortran 77 ?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it is expected that you *try a solution* before asking a question, that you come here after doing a minimal amount of research. Do read the links posted by Vladimir F and *edit your question accordingly*, including the code that you will have come up with.

Comment: How toread the files is in the link above (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262695/convert-integers-to-strings-to-create-output-filenames-at-run-time) If you need something else you have to [edit] your question and make it specific including your code.