# Fortran trim or adjustl not working while using twice

Tags: fortran, trim, fortran90

I am trying to use `trim`/`adjustl` for the following code. It seems that I'm getting either `X_eq_      10.0.dat` or `X_eq_10.0      .dat` as the output file's name where I'm expecting it to be `X_eq_10.0.dat` (no blank space). Any remedy?

```
           Program Test
           double precision:: X
           character (len=10) :: tag
           character (len=100) :: outfile

           X=10.0

           write(tag,'(f10.1)') X
           print*,'tag=',tag

           outfile='X_eq_'//trim(tag)//'.dat'
           print*,'Output file: ',outfile

           outfile='X_eq_'//trim(tag)//trim('.dat')
           print*,'Output file: ',outfile

           outfile='X_eq_'//adjustl(trim(tag))//adjustl(trim('.dat'))
           print*,'Output file: ',outfile

           End Program Test
```

I have used `gfortran` as the compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is:

`outfile='X_eq_'//trim(adjustl(tag))//'.dat'`

`adjustl` shifts the characters left, leaving trailing blanks, so you need to trim that result. It does no good to do `trim(tag)` as that is already right-adjusted. Lastly, `'.dat'` doesn't need any processing.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
write(tag,'(f10.1)') X
```

we say that we want `tag` to be of width 10 with one digit in the fractional part.  With the one decimal symbol that leaves us 8 places before the decimal: there will be blank padding beyond the (optional) sign.

This is why we see lots of blanks in `outfile='X_eq_'//trim(tag)//'.dat'`.

We can avoid this either with `adjustl` as noted in the question or another answer, or by using `0` in the edit descriptor:

```
write(tag,'(F0.1)') X
```

The `F0.d` form makes the field width the smallest appropriate field with: without leading blanks.

When `tag` has length 100 there will still be (lots of) trailing blanks, so a `trim` will be necessary.

Further, there are even ways to [avoid using an intermediary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31028207/3157076) such as `tag` without using `trim`.