# Fortran open a '.dat' file where name changable

Tags: file, fortran

I have a Fortran code which reads a "dat" file as shown below:

```
open(unit=2,file="36_st_18.dat",form="formatted",status="old")
```

However, sometimes the file name changes ( e.g., x_24_st_42_b.dat). All file names have always 'st' latters in it. How can I generalize the reading in Fortran so that I dont have to change the file name each time. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262695/convert-integers-to-strings-to-create-output-filenames-at-run-time - may not be an exact duplicate but should provide enough input for you to figure out the rest.

Comment: Just use a character variable for the file name

Comment: I did mark it a duplicate. If you need something more specific, please supply a specific recipe for the filenames you need.