# What could be the cause of "output statement overflows record, unit -5, file Internal Formatted Write"error?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

Dear Stack over flow community,
I am running a simple simulation with KPP processor and after the 9th output .dat file (out of 150) the simulation terminates with the following error message:

**forrtl: severe (66): output statement overflows record, unit -5, file Internal Formatted Write**

Compiler used:  Intel Fortran Compiler 2022.2.1 .

This might be the part of the Fortran code involved:

```
 * OPEN( unit=10, file="dyno_"//ex_no(1)//ex_no(2)//ex_no(3)//".dat")

......
......

  INTEGER i

      WRITE(10,999) (TIME-TSTART)/3600.D0,  &
                   (C(LOOKAT(i))/CFACTOR, i=1,NLOOKAT)
999   FORMAT(E24.16,100(1X,E24.16))*
```

I hope you can help with that.

Thank you in advance.

I tried checking the WRITE statement in the Fortran Integrator.f90 script but I did not find enough resources inline to check exactly what the problem was.

---

Maybe this longer description helps:

After successfully compiling a Makefile, with Intel Fortran Compiler 2022.2.1, with the options suggested by chw21, I get an executable file called **dynho.exe**.

In order to get the desired output I execute dynho.exe with the ./ command.
The output should be made of 150 .dat files, because the simulation uses 150 different sets of initial conditions.

The simulation runs but terminated after producing only 9 out of 150 expected .dat files.

The execution of the dynho.exe has been made submitting the salloc script in bwunicluster:

```
#!/bin/bash  
#SBATCH   --nodes=1
#SBATCH   --cpus-per-task=5
#SBATCH   --mem=600mb
#SBATCH   --time=27:00:00           
#SBATCH   -J  test_bwbatch               # Specify job name
#SBATCH   --mail-user=blablabla@kit.edu
#SBATCH   --mail-type=BEGIN,END,FAIL

echo "Start kpp script execution at $(date)"

./dynho.exe
```

which produces a .out file. This is the part where the forrtl error is mentioned:

```
forrtl: severe (66): output statement overflows record, unit -5, file Internal Formatted Write
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
dynho.exe          0000000000455A3A  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
dynho.exe          0000000000454737  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
dynho.exe          0000000000408629  dynho_util_mp_ini          66  dynho_Util.f90
dynho.exe          0000000000430EE6  MAIN__                     82  dynho_Main.f90
dynho.exe          000000000040385D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.28.so       000014B9B1F6D493  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
dynho.exe          000000000040377E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown

============================= JOB FEEDBACK =============================

NodeName=uc2n501
Job ID: 21896960
Cluster: uc2
User/Group: ii5664/imk-tro
State: FAILED (exit code 66)
Nodes: 1
Cores per node: 6
CPU Utilized: 00:12:52
CPU Efficiency: 9.02% of 02:22:36 core-walltime
Job Wall-clock time: 00:23:46
Memory Utilized: 5.89 MB
Memory Efficiency: 0.98% of 600.00 MB
```

I could post the dynho_Util.f90 and dynho_Main.f90 routines but I would not to overwhelm the post.

This is part of the dynho_Util.f90 :

```
     SUBROUTINE InitSaveData (j)

      USE dynho_Parameters
      INTEGER    :: j
      CHARACTER  :: ex_no(3)

      ex_no(1:2) = '000'

   
       IF(j.lt.10) then
          WRITE(ex_no(3),4) j
4         FORMAT(i1) 
       ELSEIF (j.ge.10.and.j.lt.100) then          
          WRITE(ex_no(2:3),5) j     !! This is line 66  !!
5         FORMAT(i2) 
       ELSE
          WRITE(ex_no(:),6) j
6         FORMAT(i3)
       END IF

      OPEN( unit=10, file="dynho_"//ex_no(1)//ex_no(2)//ex_no(3)//".dat")
    !  open(10, file='dynho.dat')

      END SUBROUTINE InitSaveData
```

This dynho_Util.f90 routine is a bit longer but I guess the relevant part should be this one.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You should really show more code. At the very least, all variables should be declared, but very often a full [mre] is actually necessary. Please note that the relevant write is in an **internal** write so the line you are showing is probably not the right one and you will really have to show more. An internal write is where one write into a character string.

Comment: @GiorgioT, OK let's have a look at dynho_Util.f90, especially the bit around line 66. Funny that you get the first 9 files ... how are you setting up their names?

Comment: lastchance is right, the overflow likely happens when setting-up the `ex_no` array. We have many questions and answers about numbered file names https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262695/convert-integers-to-strings-to-create-output-filenames-at-run-time (check all the duplicates linked there). If you want a specific answer about your problems, you simply have to show the relevant code. Read [mcve]. It will be around line 66. It pays off to learn to read the error messages and backtraces.

Answer (score 2):

The internal write is writing to part of the variable

```
character :: ex_no(3)
```

This is a character array, extent 3, length 1.  In the internal write

```
write(ex_no(1:2), '(I2)') 10
```

we are pointing to two *records* in the internal file, `ex_no(1)` and `ex_no(2)`.<sup>1</sup> The write, though, is writing just one record, so transfers to just `ex_no(1)`. But, `ex_no(1)` is a character of length 1 and writing two characters to that (`"10"`) is too many.

This is the reason for the fault.

Correcting this involves a complete rewrite of the logic, as you should be using a scalar character of length 3, and using a format like `(I3.3)` instead of those convoluted conditionals. You can read about the correct way to generate files like this in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1262695/3157076) and its answers.

---

<sup>1</sup> When using an array in an internal file, each element of the array is one distinct record in the transfer operation.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Vladimir, you should give more information. I don't think that the line(s) you presented contain the error. In the line above you write to a file on unit 10, but the error references an internal write on unit -5.

This usually happens when you try to write to a string variable, but the content to be written is too large, something like this:

```
program overflow
    implicit none
    character(len=10) :: some_string
    write(some_string, *) "Some content longer than", 10, "characters"
end program overflow
```

I have encountered that recently in such a situation:

```
character(len=256) :: fullname
character(len=200) :: dirpath, filename

write(fullname, "(A, A1, A)") trim(dirpath), "/", filename
```

Because `filename` wasn't trimmed, only 55 characters of the `dirpath` variable remained before the hundred-plus trailing spaces of `filename` became too long for `fullname` to handle. This went fine while the path to the directory contained less than 56 characters, but suddenly broke when it was 59.

I would suggest compiling with the options: `-O0 -g -traceback` which will give you the specific line where this happens.